# Offset is being committed even though acknowledge() is never called

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am implementing a micro service, which reads messages from Kafka queue and writes them in a database. I am using `spring-boot 1.5.6.RELEASE` and `spring-kafka 1.3.0.RELEASE`. To avoid loosing data I needed to be sure that the messages were being persisted in the database before committing the offset, so I set the `enable.auto.commit` to **false** and the `AckMode` to **MANUAL_IMMEDIATE**. Here is my Kafka configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfiguration {

  ...

  @Bean
  public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    return new HashMap<String, Object>() {
      {
        put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, servers);
        put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupIdConfig);
        put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
      }
    };
  }

  @Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
  }

  @Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);

    return factory;
  }

  ...
}
```

For the implementation of the listener I am using the `@KafkaListener` annotation. After the message is being persisted in the database, I use the `acknowledge()` method to commit the offset. Here's how my listener looks:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.myTopic}")
  public void receive(ConsumerRecord<String, String> payload, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
   // persist message here

    acknowledgment.acknowledge();

    latch.countDown();
  }
```

To test my application I stopped the database so that when the business logic tries to persist the message, a runtime exception would be thrown before the offset is being committed by the `acknowledge()` method:

1) Stopped the database.

2) Send a message with content **MESSAGE_1**.

3) Start the database.

4) Send another message with content **MESSAGE_2**.

The end result was that the database contained only **MESSAGE_2**, so the first message was lost. The only way I could get both messages in the database was when I restarted the micro service after I started the database:

1) Stopped the database.

2) Send a message with content **MESSAGE_1**.

3) Start the database.

4) Restart the micro service.

5) Send another message with content **MESSAGE_2**.

This time both of the messages were in the database. My question is why in the first scenario the offset was committed event though a runtime exception was thrown and `acknowledge()` was never called? And what is the correct way of implementing my kafka listener so that if something happens during the processing of the received message I wouldn't loose data?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to study how Apache Kafka works.

The commit offset is exactly for new consumers in the same group or for the same restarted. For the currently ran consumer it doesn't make sense and Broker tracks the current offset in the memory, so all this commits unrelated to the records fetching process.

You have to consider to `seek` consumer back to the position you are interested in: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#seek

Also see this GH issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/470

Answer (score 1):

By default kafka will commit the offsets after a specified interval, when using manual acknowledge, you should always **acknowledge** for processed records and **nack** for failed records.

Below is a sample code

```
@KafkaListener(id = "baz", topics = "${message.topic.name}", containerFactory = "containerFactory")
public void listenPEN_RE(@Payload String message,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) int offsets,
        Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {

    if (value%2==0){
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    } else {
        acknowledgment.nack(10); //sleep time should be less than max.poll.interval.ms
    }
    value++;
}
```

Here i am acknowledging the record if its even, else i am seeking the position back to current records ant retry after 10ms.